# Net Core 3.1: Soap Request returns 403 Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, soap

I have the following question. We are using net core 3.1.
We make a soap request (HttpWebRequest) to a external webservice where they only allow a whitelist of IP addresses into the portal. Our VPN Ipadress is in the whitelist.
But when i send a request (Via Visual studio debugger) it get rejected by de external webservice: 403 Unauthorized.
But when starting Fiddler and then sending the same request again, via Visual studio debugger, we get a 200 OK.
The same is with Postman. When fiddler is not running the request gets rejected. When Fiddler
is running the request is accepted and the response is 200 OK.

I dont understand what is happening, How to solve this.

NOT VIA Fiddler:

Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 408 B (233 B size)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request Priority    Highest

Response Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Date:   Thu, 28 Jul 2022 08:42:32 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
X-Powered-By:   ASP.NET

VIA Fiddler:

Status 200 OK
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 1.57 KB (1.41 KB size)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request Priority    Highest

Content-Type    text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date    Thu, 28 Jul 2022 09:01:24 GMT
Server  Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET

Comment: "403 - Forbidden" The server understands the request of the requesting client, but refuses to execute the request.  "But when starting Fiddler and then sending the same request again , it's OK." Try to use F12 to see the request  in application, check the difference between requests with Fiddler and without Fiddler.

Comment: Thx Qing. i'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Hi Qing i have update the question with the responses NOT via Fiddler and Via Fiddler.

Comment: You need to check the `Request`, not reponse. Find the difference between requests with Fiddler and without Fiddler.

Comment: Hi Qing, the Request is the same. No Difference. I think that because the external webservice is validating the IPadres they are rejecting it. How can i see which IPadres is be-ing send in the request?